# php preg replace file extension with parameter / query string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i have a problem with preg replace in php.

I need to get file extension which ends with parameters like:

```
../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.2.1  
../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.2.1  
../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1  
../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.2.1  
../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.2.1
```

etc...

i try to use this function:

```
pathinfo($path[1], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

but it gives last section after the dot character which is "1"

i try to get css file and replace the paths in url with spesific path name in order to extensions...

Here is my code example:

```
class class_name {

    private $img_exts, $font_exts;

    function __construct() {
        $this->img_exts = array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif');
        $this->font_exts = array('ttf','woff','eot','otf');
    }

    function get_css_file() {
        $css = file_get_contents('font-awesome.css');
        $css = preg_replace_callback('/url\((?!data)"?\'?(.*?)"?\'?\)/',array($this,'replace_files_callback'), $file);
        return $css;
    }

    function replace_file_callback($file) {
        $ext = pathinfo($path[1], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        // here is the code which i failed!!!
        $ext_niddle = preg_replace('/(.*)?(\.)?(.*)?\.([a-zA-z0-9]{2,4})\??\#?(.*)?/','$4',$path[1]);
        $fname = basename($path[1]);

        if (in_array($ext_niddle, $this->img_exts)) {
            return "url('../img/$fname')";
        } elseif (in_array($ext_niddle, $this->font_exts)) {
            return "url('../fonts/$fname')";
        } else {
            return "url('../data/$fname')";
        }
    }
}
```

So i failed!

I try to replace this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.2.1');
  src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.2.1') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1') format('woff'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.2.1') format('truetype'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.2.1') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

to this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.2.1');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.2.1') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.2.1') format('truetype'), url('../data/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.2.1') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I'm curious about file names with:
../folder/font.name.ttf?ver=1.2.3
or something like this...

if you find a inappropriate code, please help me!

I'm gonna use it with this project: http://jslibgen.com/

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $uri = "../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.2.1";

    preg_match("/\/(.+?)\.(.+?)(#|\?)/", $uri, $m);
    $ext = $m[2];

    echo $ext;
?>
```

Comment: i'm so appreciated for your answer but it's not working for standart filenames like:

file-name-something.img

and:

file.name.jpg

Answer (score 0):

How about using [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
$data = array(
'../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.2.1',
'../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.2.1',
'../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1',
'../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.2.1',
'../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.2.1',
);
foreach ($data as $url) {
    $parse = parse_url($url);
    $fname = basename($parse['path']);
    $ext = pathinfo($fname,  PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    echo "fname=$fname\text=$ext\n";
}
```

**output:**

```
fname=fontawesome-webfont.eot   ext=eot
fname=fontawesome-webfont.eot   ext=eot
fname=fontawesome-webfont.woff  ext=woff
fname=fontawesome-webfont.ttf   ext=ttf
fname=fontawesome-webfont.svg   ext=svg
```

Comment: it gives this error: Undefined index: path on line: $fname = basename($parse['path']);

Comment: @dreamlore: Really strange, what's the ouptput of `print_r($parse)`?

Comment: it works here: http://writecodeonline.com/php/ but not my server. i need to debug, i guess... i checked with print_r and there is no mistake. Array ( [path] => fancybox_buttons.png )... weird...